# Excel does not work the sum in the status bar for a file generated in C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

In Excel does not work the sum in the status bar for a file generated in C#. In the code I set the cell format as a number. Any idea what might be going on?

My code:

```
oWorksheet.Cells[vLinhaCelula, 7].NumberFormat = "0";
oWorksheet.Cells[vLinhaCelula, 7].Value = vValorNF.Replace(".", ""); 
oWorksheet.Cells[vLinhaCelula, 7].HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;
```

[image: Format is Number]

[image: But the sum dont work]

[image: I need this]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: My guess is that `vValorNF.Replace(".", "");` is returning a string, and therefore the cell becomes a string regardless of the number formatting. Try specifically creating a double `double num = Double.Parse(vValorNF.Replace(".", ""));` and then assigning `oWorksheet.Cells[vLinhaCelula, 7].Value = num;`

Comment: I did the conversion to decimal and it worked exactly as I wanted.
Thank you very much cph!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that vValorNF.Replace(".", ""); is returning a string, and therefore the cell becomes a string regardless of the number formatting. Try specifically creating a double or decimal

```
double num = Double.Parse(vValorNF.Replace(".", ""));
```

and then assigning

```
oWorksheet.Cells[vLinhaCelula, 7].Value = num;
```